# Looking for some guidance on how to code a writer for a given "AST" (DynamoDB)

Tags: scala

As a personal project, I am writing yet another Scala library for DynamoDb. It contains many interesting aspect such as reading and writing from an AST (just as Json), handling HTTP request, streaming data…

In order to be able able to communicate with DynamoDb, one needs to be able to read from / to the DynamoDb format (the “AST”). I extracted this reading / writing from / to the AST in a minimalist library: `dynamo-ast`. It contains two main type classes: `DynamoReads[_]` and `DynamoWrites[_]` (deeply inspired from Play Json).

I successfully coded the reading part of the library ending with a very simple code such as :

```
trait DynamoRead[A] { self =>
   def read(dynamoType: DynamoType): DynamoReadResult[A]
}

case class TinyImage(url: String, alt: String)

val dynamoReads: DynamoReads[TinyImage] = {
  for {
    url <- read[String].at(“url”)
    alt <- read[String].at(“alt”)
  } yield (url, alt) map (TinyImage.apply _).tupled
}

dynamoReads.reads(dynamoAst) //yield DynamoReadResult[TinyImage]
```

At that point, I thought I wrote the most complicated part of the library and the `DynamoWrite[_]` part would be a piece of cake. I am however stuck on writing the DynamoWrite part. I was a fool.

My goal is to provide a very similar “user experience” with the `DynamoWrite[_]` and keep it as simple as possible such as :

```
val dynamoWrites: DynamoWrites[TinyImage] = {
  for {
    url <- write[String].at(“url”)
    alt <- write[String].at(“alt”)
  } yield (url, alt) map (TinyImage.unapply _) //I am not sure what to yield here nor how to code it
}

dynamoWrites.write(TinyImage(“http://fake.url”, “The alt desc”)) //yield DynamoWriteResult[DynamoType]
```

Since this library is deeply inspired from Play Json library (because I like its simplicity) I had a look at the sources several times. I kind of dislike the way the writer part is coded because to me, it adds a lot of overhead (basically each time a field a written, a new JsObject is created with one field and the resulting JsObject for a complete class is the merge of all the JsObjects containing one field).

From my understanding, the DynamoReads part can be written with only one trait (`DynamoRead[_]`). The `DynamoWrites` part however requires at least two such as :

```
trait DynamoWrites[A] {
  def write(a: A): DynamoWriteResult[DynamoType]
}

trait DynamoWritesPath[A] {
  def write(path:String, a: A): DynamoWriteResult[(String, DynamoType)]
}
```

The `DynamoWrites[_]` is to write plain String, Int… and the `DynamoWritesPath[_]` is to write a tuple of `(String, WhateverTypeHere)` (to simulate a “field”).

So writing `write[String].at(“url”)` would yield a `DynamoWritesPath[String]`. Now I have several issues :

- I have no clue how to write flatMap for my `DynamoWritesPath[_]`
- what should yield a for comprehension to be able to obtain a `DynamoWrite[TinyImage]`

What I wrote so far (totally fuzzy and not compiling at all, looking for some help on this). Not committed at the moment (gist): https://gist.github.com/louis-forite/cad97cc0a47847b2e4177192d9dbc3ae

To sum up, I am looking for some guidance on how to write the `DynamoWrites[_]` part. My goal is to provide for the client the most straight forward way to code a `DynamoWrites[_]` for a given type. My non goal is to write the perfect library and keep it a zero dependency library.

Link to the library: https://github.com/louis-forite/dynamo-ast

Comment: Any reason why you don't have: 
`trait DynamoRead[A] { self =>
   def read(dynamoType: DynamoType): A
}`

Comment: Sure, when you read something, it might be either a success either a failure, so instead of returning a plain A we wrap it into a failure / success class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `Reads` is a covariant functor. That means it has `map`. It can also be seen as a `Monad` which means it has `flatMap` (although a monad is overkill unless you need the previous field in order to know how to process the next):

```
trait Reads[A] {
  def map [B] (f: A => B): Reads[B]
  def flatMap [B](f: A => Reads[B]): Reads[B] // not necessary, but available
}
```

The reason for this, is that to transform a `Reads[Int]` to a `Reads[String]`, you need to first read the `Int`, then apply the `Int => String` function.

But a `Writes` is a contravariant functor. It has `contramap` where the direction of the types is reversed:

```
trait Writes[A] {
  def contramap [B](f: B => A): Reads[B]
}
```

The type on the function is reversed because to transform a `Writes[Int]` to a `Writes[String]` you must receive the `String` from the caller, apply the transformation `String => Int` and **then** write the `Int`.

I don't think it makes sense to provide for-comprehension syntax (flatMap) for the `Writes` API.

```
// here it is clear that you're extracting a string value
url <- read[String].at(“url”)

// but what does this mean for the write method?
url <- write[String].at("url")
// what is `url`?
```

That's probably why play doesn't provide one either, and why they focus on their combinator syntax (using the `and` function, their version of applicative functor builder?).

For reference: http://blog.tmorris.net/posts/functors-and-things-using-scala/index.html

You can achieve a more consistent API by using something like the `and` method in play json:

```
(write[String]("url") and write[String]("alt"))(unlift(TinyImage.unapply))

(read[String]("url") and read[String]("alt"))(TinyImage.apply)

// unfortunately, the type ascription is necessary in this case
(write[String]("url") and write[String]("alt")) {(x: TinyImage) =>
  (x.url, x.alt)
}

// transforming
val instantDynamoType: DynamoFormat[Instant] = 
  format[String].xmap(Instant.parse _)((_: Instant).toString)
```

You can still use for-comprehension for the reads, although it's a bit over-powered (sort of implies that fields must be processed in-sequence, while that's not technically necessary).

Comment: You make a really good point here. I wondered many times if providing a for comprehension makes a lot of sense. It seems not but was trying to make it as simple as possible. I was trying to introduce as little DSL as possible to reduce learning curse to its minimum. So you would suggest to go for a functional builder approach ? Where Writes can be concatenated ?

Comment: Yes. Also a way to combine reads and writes into the equivalent of a `Format`, where I can have a method like `xmap` (or `inmap` in play): `def xmap[B](encode: A => B)(decode: B => A)`. For inspiration: http://mpilquist.github.io/blog/2013/06/01/scodec-part-2/ or search for "play json inmap"

Comment: I understand the conveniency of `and` because you have a unified way to use Reads and Writes but I am also wondering if there is an easier way: debugging `and` can be cumbersome and it is hard to tell what is happening. On the other side, for comprehension are crystal clear.

Comment: I finally understood what you meant and ended up integrating `Cats` for my lib. I implemented `Monad` instance for the `Read` (even if it is overkill, I have been told that it would be nice to provide it). For the `Writer,` I am going to implement `ContravariantCartesian`, as you suggested. Many thanks for the useful insights